# Attempted floating of nav bar to the right but due to the presence of a flexbox seems to be failing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reengage my knowledge of Html/CSS but I have hit a dead-end as I can not float my navbar to the right while initiating the flex-box to keep items in a row. Also, initial attempts to create the model navbar forced content to go under the navbar and sometimes forced the navbar background to disappear. Could someone maybe revise the code and tell me what next to do.

```
<div class = "header">
    <section class = "logo-section">
      <img src = "#" alt= ""> 
      <div class  = "logo-writing">
        <div><strong> Adakole's test Program </div>
          <div>IG: test</div></strong>
      </div>
    </section>
  <div class = "navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><strong><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></strong></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
<body>
<div> Why is my code not working?</div>
</body>
```

```
.header{
  background-color: #CCFFFF;
  display:flex;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.logo-section{
  color:grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.logo-section:hover{
  color: #FFCCCC;
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar {
  margin-right: 1%;
  float:right;
}
.navbar ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:flex;
}
.navbar a{
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navbar a:hover{
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Div is a block level element, so it can not have float property. But if you add `display: inline;` it can have float. Try this;

Edit*

Dude you have some misunderstand of using HTML tags. The snippets will work as you wanted. But you have to understand how HTML tags works. So here is the snippet;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "header">

            <section class = "logo-section">

            <img src = "#" alt= "">
            <div class = "logo-writing">
                <strong>
                    <div>Adakole's test Program </div>
                    <div>IG: kol.eee</div>
                </strong>
            </div>
            </section>

            <div class = "navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><strong><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></strong></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class= "main">
            <div id = "title">  
                <h1> The Death of a Hero</h1>
                <h3 id = "name">"Dr. Herman Boulang"</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <style>
            .header
            {
                background-color: #CCFFFF;
                display:flex;
                position:sticky;
                justify-content: space-between;
                top:0;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            .logo-section
            {
                color:grey;
                opacity: 0.5;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-family: Helvetica, Sans-serif;
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
            .logo-section:hover
            {
                color: #FFCCCC;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .navbar
            {
                margin-right: 1%;
                float:right;
            }
            .navbar ul
            {
                list-style-type: none;
                display:flex;
            }
            .navbar a
            {
                display:inline-block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: grey;
                opacity: 0.5;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                background-color: #DDDDDD;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 15%;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            .navbar a:hover
            {
                background-color: #FFCCCC;
            }
            body
            {
                background-color: #cddfff;
            }
            #title
            {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 40px;
                font-family: Helvetica;
                color: #ffffff
            }
            #name
            {
                margin-top: -40px;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

You are using flex for header, so floats will never work. You cant look at `justify-content`, `justify-self` for alignment. So you have two elements to align, i used `justify-content: space-between;` so there will be a space between these two elements. But please first learn how to write tags.

Comment: I have tried that, but it still seems to not work. Could you vet the code on https://codepen.io/Koleworkspace/pen/RwVaPBY

Comment: @Adakole i looked at it and i edited my answer. You got to understand how HTML tags works. Also you don't have to use flex for header.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I pretty much just started coding personally today so everything's pretty much theoretical for me. I will look further into tags though. Again, thank you!!!